# Are non-homogeneous second order ODE's reductible to systems of first order ODEs?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

In particular, I am thinking on a second order ODE like

\begin{equation}
u''=f(x)
\end{equation}

but that doesn't seem reductible to a matrix problem like

\begin{equation}
x'=Ax
\end{equation}

Comment: You're right, it would reduce to something like $x' = Ax + f$ instead.

Comment: I added an additional paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $u’’(x)=f(x)$. Introduce $x_1=u$, $x_2=x_1’$ to obtain:

$$x_1’=x_2$$
$$x_2’=f(x).$$
 If $\mathbf{x}=[x_1, x_2]$ then

$$\dot{\mathbf{x}}=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\mathbf{x}+\begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 1\end{bmatrix}f(x)$$

This equation cannot be cast into a homogenous equation because we had an external forcing in the beginning.

You could artificially reduce the sytem by introducing the function $F(x)$ with the condition $F’’(x)=f(x)$. If we introduce the additional substitution $u=z+F$ then we will obtain a homogeneous ode:

$$ u’’ =z’’+F’’=z’’+f(x)=f(x)$$
$$z’’ =0.$$